# iPhone Memory, What to trust?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory

I have been having some memory problems with an app. Im getting to a stage now where nothing really gives me a solid answer in terms of memory.

At first I used the Allocations profiler which I dont think seems to work that well at all, I think this is due to the fact most of my code is in Obj-C++ meaning it cant track the memory correctly.

With the Allocations profiler it tells me the app uses 32mb of memory and around this point it says it has low memory and sometimes crashes out. However, within other parts of the applications its used up to 40mb and never crashed out.

I found this code chunk:

http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/iphone/Determining_Available_Memory.20081203.html

Which appears to tell me im using 70mb of memory, when I get the low memory warning it says I have 2mb - 4mb left of unused memory. Which seems more reasonable, but its almost double what the profiler says!

The only thing I can think of is just ignoring it all and reducing the amount of memory used by my app as much as possible.

Comment: Have you checked the leaks in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore it all and reduce the size of your app is actually a good way to proceed. Make sure that you're responding to memory warnings by purging anything in memory that you don't need. Remember that different devices have different amounts of memory, and you may need to use even less than you think, at least if you want to support those older devices.